# What does 'wintry-wise' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

In the Financial Times article titled '[Now it can be told](https://www.ft.com/content/32e9e57a-0fd0-11e3-99e0-00144feabdc0)' (old, therefore not behind a paywall), the author and celebrated historian Simon Schama writes:

> J H Plumb, who had been my professor at Cambridge, was its editor and he thought I was the person to finish it. I couldn’t say no, although I remembered the words of the wintry-wise preacher of Ecclesiastes: "My sonne ... of the making of many books there is no end and much studie wearies the flesh."

What does 'wintry-wise' mean?

I thought '-wise' could only be affixed to a noun. Is that not true in general?

Comment: I would say a "wintry-wise" person means a very wise person, like a being wise the way the winter is steadfast and serious in being cold!

Comment: @Cardinal Thank you. That makes sense. Would you say that 'wintry-wise' is perhaps an alternative way to say 'wintry-mannered'?

Comment: Yeah, that might be  the case as well, I am not a native speaker of English so, you can take whatever I say with a grain of salt! For some reason, I thought the context is such that the author wants to describe the "wiseness" of that person.

Comment: I wonder if it might refer to the wisdom that has accumulated in old age, which could be called the winter of life.

Comment: Yes, I think Schama intended the expression to refer to wisdom, not _-wise_ as in _clockwise_. The Wikipedia article on Ecclesiastes (a book of the Bible, for those who don't know) contains the comment "Scholars disagree about the themes of Ecclesiastes: whether it is positive and life-affirming, or deeply pessimistic." Presumably Schama sees it as pessimistic (cold and gloomy).

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. That also makes sense. Is it safe to say that 'wintry-wise' is basically 'wintrily wise'?

Comment: That would be my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the pessimistic and rather bleak outlook of the preacher in Ecclesiastes. For example, he thought "*the race is not to the swift, nor the battle to the strong, nor bread to the wise, nor riches to the intelligent, nor favor to the men of skill; but time and chance happen to them all*” (Ecclesiastes 9:11). Or otherwise: Life's efforts are in vain compared to the influence of chance; just enjoy what comes.

You will find more on the preacher in https://www.britannica.com/topic/Ecclesiastes-Old-Testament

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That quote is also very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it just means old.

I have seen that old fashioned expression before.
"wise" because he has seen many winters, ie... Old

It also refers to the white hair, colored like winter ie... Old

> He had charming wintry hair.